# Angular2 - Adding new <li> item onClick event

Tags: angular

I use *ngFor iterating an array in order to show them in a list, but i can't add a new item in my list. During Onclick Event i get an empty li. Probably i am not linking correct something? A directive? or what? Maybe i use a wrong variable?

My exporting class where i have my constructor:

```
export class ContactInfo {
    constructor( public description:string) { }
}
```

i load the above class in my app.component.ts and the code follows. I use templateUrl where my main html exists (you can see it at the 3rd code part).

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ContactInfo} from './contactinfo';
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
 })
export class AppComponent { 

    title = 'Angular App';
    name = "Fotis";
    lastName = "Karalis";
    myTitle = 'Web Developer';
    information = [
      new ContactInfo('HTML5 = Regards DOM'),
      new ContactInfo('CSS3 = Regards DOM styling')
    ];
    myInfo = this.information[0];
    addInfo(newInfo:string) {
      if (newInfo) {
        this.information.push(newInfo);
      }
    }
 }
```

And my main app.component html is:

```
<h1>Project: {{title}}</h1>
<span>{{name}}</span>
<span>{{lastName}}</span>
<a href="#">Position: {{myTitle}}</a>
<h4>Skills</h4>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#info of information">
   <pre>{{ info.description }} </pre>
  </li>
</ul>

<input #newInfo
  (keyup.enter)="addInfo(newInfo.value)"
  (blur)="addInfo(newInfo.value); newInfo.value='' ">

<button (click)=addInfo(newInfo.value)>Add</button>
```

Comment: why to use `keyup.enter` and `blur` ? and whats the error you got ?

Comment: I am not getting any error, just an empty li when pressing the add button or when blur.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is working demo for your problem:

> http://plnkr.co/edit/fictP28Vqn74YqrwM1jW?p=preview

Just changed your method like this:

```
addInfo(newInfo:string) {
    if (newInfo) {
        this.information.push(new ContactInfo(newInfo));
    }
  }
```

you have not created a new instance for the `exported` class `ContactInfo` because of this your string is not properly pushing in the array.

Answer (score 4):

When you add

```
this.information.push(newInfo);
```

You don't add ContactInfo instance but string which doesn't have description property.