# Angular2 - Add item with click event

Tags: angular, onclick

I know it's been asked before but the best answer i found is for 9 month ago : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415605/angular2-adding-new-li-item-onclick-event) and doesn't work with new angular

I want to push an `<li>` or any other item to my HTML with simple click in angular2.

How should i do it?

i want to re-create [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/fictP28Vqn74YqrwM1jW?p=previe) plunker in new angular

Comment: Please provide more information of what you are trying to do and I will help you.

Comment: If the list items are from an array, just push a new entry.

Comment: let's say we have a list and i want to add an item to it.as simple as that.

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. Give a [mcve] of *your code* demonstrating what you've achieved so far and the specific problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for then:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

class ContactInfo {
  constructor(public description: string) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let info of information">
      <pre>{{ info.description }}</pre>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input #newInfo (keyup.enter)="addInfo(newInfo.value)" (blur)="addInfo(newInfo.value); newInfo.value='' ">

  <button (click)="addInfo(newInfo.value)">Add</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  information = [
    new ContactInfo('HTML5 = Regards DOM'),
    new ContactInfo('CSS3 = Regards DOM styling')
  ];

  addInfo(newInfo: string) {
    if (newInfo) {
      this.information.push(new ContactInfo(newInfo));
    }
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8SSAa0mEK9YB1IxIHaoK

Answer (score 0):

try this  :

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

class ContactInfo {
  constructor(public description: string) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let info of information">
      <pre>{{ info.description }}</pre>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <input #newInfo (keyup.enter)="addInfo(newInfo.value)" (onclick)="addInfo(newInfo.value); newInfo.value='' ">
  
  <button (click)="addInfo(newInfo.value)">Add</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  information = [];
  
  myInfo = this.information[0];
  
  addInfo(newInfo: string) {
    if (newInfo) {
      this.information.push(new ContactInfo(newInfo));
    }
  }

}
```